# How to reference the current Viewcontroller from a Sprite Kit Scene

Tags: ios, reference, sprite-kit, viewcontroller, skscene

I'm having a hard time finding the answer to this question I assume is not that hard.

How can I reference methods and properties defined on a viewcontroller from a SKScene ?

And building on that: How can you reference the ViewController from a SKScene that was loaded from within another SKScene?

Comment: Retrieving the current rootViewController should be enough for you, unless you need to do something specific. You can do it like this [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController; . Other solution would be to subclass SKScene and give it presentingVC property, set this property upon creating each scene to send it around.

Comment: You should avoid to reference `UIViewController` from `SKScene`, because it breaks MVC pattern

Comment: Like @AndreyGordeev mentions, you should really avoid referencing you Scene's viewController directly. It should never have to know about the viewController directly.

What could however make sense is to implement a delegate protocol on your SKScene-subclass and have the viewController set up to be this delegate. Perhaps you should take a step back and inform us what you are trying to achieve, rather than a particular way to implement this?

Comment: I added Game Center authentication logic to my main ViewController. FYI I'm working with a single viewcontroller as this is a simple game. I keep properties on my viewcontroller that keep track of general GameCenter availability + the authenticated user. Now, when my game ends, I want to report my Scores to gamecenter. So I need to get in touch with my viewcontroller in order to check if the gamecenter functionality is available and the user is logged on. I don't want to pass the properties for this to my SKScene because I'm not sure what will happen when user gets unauthenticated during play.

Answer (score 13):

A better option than my "back reference" answer is to use a protocol to explicitly define the methods that a `SKScene` subclass expects the `UIViewController` subclass to implement. Here are the steps you'll need to go through.

1) Define the protocol (contract) that the `UIViewController` will need to adopt and conform to:

```
protocol GameManager{
    func loadHomeScene()
    func loadGameScene(level:Int)
    func loadHighScoreScene()
}
```

2) The `UIViewController` subclass now adopts the protocol:

`class GameViewController: UIViewController,GameManager{`

3) The `GameScene` gets an ivar that references the `UIViewController`:

`var gameManager:GameManager?`

4) When the `GameManager` needs to call the `UIViewController`, it does so like this:

`gameManager.loadHighScoreScene()`

We now have a well-defined contract of what a `GameManager` is. Any other developers (and the current developer's future self) that work on this project now know which methods a `GameManager` should implement. This means we could easily port this code to a different project (and thus a different `UIViewController`) and it would still work as long as this new `UIViewController` adopted the `GameManager` protocol.

Similarly, if we decided to move our scene navigation code out of the view controller, and instead placed it in a singleton class, this singleton class would merely need to adopt the `GameManager` protocol.

### Which approach to use?

This thread gives 4 approaches to solving the problem, and I have personally used all 4. Here's my take on them:

**1) Hard-coding a call to the `UIViewController` subclass:**

`(self.view!.window!.rootViewController as! GameViewController).loadGameScene(1)`

*Advantage*: 1 line of code!

*Disadvantage*: A very tight coupling of 2 classes, without an explicit contract.

**2) Using a pointer back to the `UIViewController`:**

*Advantages*: Very little code required, No protocol required.

Disadvantages: Tight coupling of 2 classes. No explicit contract.

**3) Using `NSNotificationCenter`:**

*Advantage*: Loosely coupled classes.

*Disadvantages*: more code needed to set up the broadcaster, receiver, and callback methods. Harder to trace and debug the code. No explicit contract. The "one-to many" capability of notifications is nice, but doesn't help us here.

**4) Creating a protocol:**

*Advantages*: An explicit contract. The gods of MVC will be pleased.

*Disadvantage*: More code to write (but much less than notifications).

Answer (score 9):

You should avoid to reference `UIViewController` from `SKScene`, because it breaks MVC pattern.

As an alternative way you can use `NSNotificationCenter` to notify `UIViewController` about high score:

In `ViewController`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(reportScore:)
        name:@"ReportScore"
        object:nil];
}


-(void)reportScore:(NSNotification *) notification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSNumber *scores = (NSNumber *)[userInfo objectForKey:@"scores"];
    // do your stuff with GameCenter....
}


- (void) dealloc
{
    // If you don't remove yourself as an observer, the Notification Center
    // will continue to try and send notification objects to the deallocated
    // object.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

In `SKScene`:

```
- (void)gameOver {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.scores forKey:@"scores"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"ReportScore" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

Comment: in SKScene, you forgot NSNumber's closing ']'. Thanks for answer by the way.

Answer (score 5):

in theory you should not do that but in practice...

```
self.view.window.rootViewController
```

Comment: The Swift version is even uglier


`(self.view!.window!.rootViewController as! GameViewController).loadGameScene()`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your NSNotification method for exiting a sprite kit scene back to the calling view controller.  This is a simple way to jump back to UIKit & will post my code.  I'm working is swift & just added 4 lines of code for those working in Swift.  This code was added to the view controller in the viewDidLoad function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameLevels.unarchiveFromFile("GameLevels") as? GameLevels{
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        //set up notification so scene can get back to this view controller
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "quitToLevel:", name: "quitToLevelID", object: nil)
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}

// Function to pop this view controller and go back to my Levels screen
func quitToLevel(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

I added this code to my touchesBegan function in my SKscene to get back to the view controller

```
            else if nodeTouched.name == "quit"
        {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("quitToLevelID", object: nil)
        }
```

Now when I hit the "quit" labelNode, it will let me run a function called quitToLevel in the view controller that presented my scene. This function pops me back to my main screen since I'm using a navigation controller but could be used for any purpose.

I tried several other methods of exiting a scene, but had issues if I was jumping around in multiple scenes of loosing the reference back to the view controller.  I can use this method from any scene

Comment: great solution because it was as simple as you can get adding only a few lines.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but how about a "back reference" from your SKScene subclass to the GameViewController? Something like this:

```
// call from GameViewController
let scene = HomeScene(size:screenSize, scaleMode:SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill, viewController: self)
```

Your SKScene subclass looks like this:

```
class HomeScene: SKScene {
    var viewController:GameViewController
    init(size:CGSize, scaleMode:SKSceneScaleMode, viewController:GameViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController
        super.init(size:size)
        self.scaleMode = scaleMode
    }
}
```

and later:

```
func gameOver(){
    self.viewController.loadHighScoreScene()
}
```

SKNode and its subclasses already have a `.parent` and a `.scene` property, so it's not like this approach is unheard of.
Yeah, we're hard-coding a dependency and more tightly coupling our code, but we're writing *less* code, so it can't be all bad.