# Showing AdMob interstitial in GameScene(SKScene)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, admob, skscene

In my gameviewcontroller I can present the interstitial like this:

```
    var request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [GAD_SIMULATOR_ID];
    var interstit = GADInterstitial()
    interstit = interstit2
    interstit.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    interstit.loadRequest(request)
    println("req loaded admob")

if interstit.isReady{
       interstit.presentFromRootViewController(self)
       request()
    }
```

But I want to call the same interstitial in the GameScene(SKScene), and presentfromrootviewcontroller is not working in there, what is the solution?

Comment: send a nsnotification to view controller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827783/how-to-reference-the-current-viewcontroller-from-a-sprite-kit-scene

Answer (score 1):

That's the answer in Swift:

```
let currentViewController:UIViewController=UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!

interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(currentViewController)
```